# VBA - looping multiple record sets

Tags: vba, ms-access, recordset

I think I have a fairly simple question to answer. The below code works perfectly as is, with an end result of populating 2 of my userform's combo boxes with field data from an Access data base. I still have several more combo boxes to fill with access data. I am looking for a way to loop through multiple SQL statements in a single record set rather than needing to create a new record set for each SQL query. As always, much appreciated.

```
Const conStrAccess As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
Source=C:\Users\Andy\Desktop\Database\IATC.accdb;Persist Security 
Info=False;"
Const providerSQL As String = "SELECT DISTINCT [Provider Name] FROM 
tblProvider ORDER BY [Provider Name];"
Const employeeSQL As String = "SELECT DISTINCT [Employee Name] FROM 
tblEmployee ORDER BY [Employee Name];"    

Dim aConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim providerData As ADODB.Recordset
Dim employeeData As ADODB.Recordset

Set aConn = New ADODB.Connection
Set providerData = New ADODB.Recordset
Set employeeData = New ADODB.Recordset

aConn.ConnectionString = conStrAccess
aConn.Open

aConn.ConnectionString = conStrAccess
aConn.Open

providerData.Open providerSQL, aConn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
providerData.MoveFirst

With Me.cbxProvider
    .Clear
    Do
        .AddItem providerData![Provider Name]
        providerData.MoveNext
    Loop Until providerData.EOF
End With

employeeData.Open employeeSQL, aConn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
employeeData.MoveFirst

With Me.cbxEmployee
    .Clear
    Do
        .AddItem employeeData![Employee Name]
        employeeData.MoveNext
    Loop Until employeeData.EOF
End With
```

Comment: there appears to be a typo in your code ... _aConn.Open_ and preceeding line are there twice

Comment: you have to use two recordsets because you have two tables (two data sources)  ... are you asking if there is any way to combine the two recordsets into one sql query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In programming a useful rule of thumb is "don't repeat yourself" ("DRY").  If you find you're writing the same code over and over with consistent variations, then you should refactor that code out into a separate method, with some parameters to manage the variations.

Untested:

```
Sub Main()

    Const conStrAccess As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data " & _
        "Source=C:\Users\Andy\Desktop\Database\IATC.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"

    Const providerSQL As String = "SELECT DISTINCT [Provider Name] FROM tblProvider ORDER BY [Provider Name]"
    Const employeeSQL As String = "SELECT DISTINCT [Employee Name] FROM tblEmployee ORDER BY [Employee Name]"

    Dim aConn As New ADODB.Connection
    aConn.Open conStrAccess

    FillListBox aConn, providerSQL, Me.cbxProvider
    FillListBox aConn, employeeSQL, Me.cbxEmployee
    '...more lists...

    aConn.Close

End Sub

'Fill a combobox from a single-field SQL query
Sub FillComboBox(con As ADODB.Connection, SQL As String, cb)
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open SQL, con, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
    With cb
        .Clear
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            .AddItem rs.Fields(0).Value
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
    rs.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider not using any recordsets at all as MS Access form comboboxes and listboxes can use tables and queries as rowsources:

```
Dim var As Variant, varList As Variant

varList = Array("Provider", "Employee")

For Each var in varList

    sql = "SELECT DISTINCT [" & var & " Name] " _
           & " FROM tbl" & var & " ORDER BY [" & var & " Name];"

    With Me.Form.Controls("cbx" & var)
        .RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
        .RowSource = sql
        .Requery
    End With

Next var
```